# React Native dynamic API url

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

I am working on a app that should scan barcode and insert the upc barcode to the api url, so i can get information about a product. I can retrieve the upc barcode, but i am stuck with inserting the barcode to the api url. 
[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM6yF.jpg)

### Api.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScanditSDK from './components/ScanditSDK'

export default class Api extends Component{
  getUPCfromApi = (upc) => {
   try {
    let response = fetch(
      'https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/'+ upc + '/API_KEY');
    let responseJson = response.json();
    return responseJson;
    console.log('response',responseJson);
  }  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
 }
  render(){
   return(
   <ScanditSDK 
   upc={this.upc}
   getUPCfromApi={this.getUPCfromApi}
   />
   ) 
  }
}
```

ScanditSDK.js contains scanner module. Inside the onScan method i am calling getUpcFromApi(upc) which i made inside Api.js

### ScanditSDK.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  findNodeHandle,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {
  BarcodePicker,
  ScanditModule,
  ScanSession,
  Barcode,
  SymbologySettings,
  ScanSettings
} from 'react-native-scandit';

import Api from '../Api';
ScanditModule.setAppKey('APIKEY');



export class ScanditSDK extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      upc: '',
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.settings = new ScanSettings();
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.EAN13, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.EAN8, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.UPCA, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.UPCE, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.CODE39, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.ITF, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.QR, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.DATA_MATRIX, true);
    this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.CODE128, true);
   // this.settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.Symbology.MICROQR, true);

    /* Some 1d barcode symbologies allow you to encode variable-length data. By default, the
       Scandit BarcodeScanner SDK only scans barcodes in a certain length range. If your
       application requires scanning of one of these symbologies, and the length is falling
       outside the default range, you may need to adjust the "active symbol counts" for this
       symbology. This is shown in the following few lines of code. */
    this.settings.getSymbologySettings(Barcode.Symbology.CODE39)
      .activeSymbolCounts = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
    /* For details on defaults and how to calculate the symbol counts for each symbology, take
       a look at http://docs.scandit.com/stable/c_api/symbologies.html. */
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scanner.startScanning();
  }

  getUPCfromApi = (upc) => {
    try {
      let response = fetch(
        'https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/'+ upc + '/API_KEY');
      let responseJson = response.json();
      return responseJson;
      console.log('response',responseJson);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <BarcodePicker
                onScan={(session) => { this.onScan(session) }}
                scanSettings= { this.settings }
        ref={(scan) => { this.scanner = scan }}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
    </View>
    );
  }

  onScan(session) {
    this.setState({upc:session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].data })
    alert(session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].data + " " + session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].symbology);
    this.getUPCfromApi(this.state.upc)
  }
}
```

Comment: Scanner.js should be named ScanditSDK.js

Answer (score 0):

Try change `onScan(session) {...}` to `onScan = (session) => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

To solve an issue like this, I will advise you have a method that dynamically adds the barcode in the API URL then you call the function and assign its value to a variable and that is what you will call in your fetch.

```
function generateAPiUrl(barcode) {
    const apiUrl = 
`https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/${upc}/${API_KEY}`

  return apiUrl;
}
```

Comment: but it does " this.getUPCfromApi(this.state.upc) is not a function" inside onScan function